# Unable to find gradle dependency for the below git

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView
Im adding guageview in my application but unable to include library .

Tried with all the below:

```
compile 'org.codeandmagic.android.gauge:GaugeView:1.0'
compile 'org.codeandmagic.android.gauge:GaugeView:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'org.codeandmagic.android.gauge:gaugeview:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Can any one please help me out?

More details u can see here :- http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-gaugeview-library/

Comment: The project is not available to be added as a gradle dependency.

Comment: then if need to use this library in my application how can I do ? is there any other alternative? @KNeerajLal

Comment: Download the project as zip and add it to your project, just like adding a new package.